# How do I make a for loop ask a user for the same input again after an Exception?

Tags: java

So to clarify, when the program asks the user for number 1: if the user were to input a letter, I need the program to tell the user that there was an input mismatch, then ask the user for number 1 again. This needs to be achieved using only one single for loop, and there can be no negative numbers that affect the sum or the average. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class fivePositiveNumbers{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userNumber;
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("This program will give the sum and average of 5 positive integers,");
      
      for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
         System.out.println("Enter number " + i + ": ");
         try{
            userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum = sum + userNumber;
            if(userNumber <= 0){
               throw new Exception("The integer must be positive.");
            }
         } catch(InputMismatchException e){
               System.out.println("This data type is incorrect.");
               keyboard.nextLine();
         } catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               keyboard.nextLine();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + " and the average of your 5 numbers is " + sum / 5 + ".");
   }
}
```

Comment: Adding a `i--;` line inside the catchs doesn't do the trick?

Comment: I would only add this to the `catch(InputMismatchException e)`. Or better, just remote `i++` from the for-loop and add an unconditional `i++` at the end of the for-loop, after the catches. I would also remove `catch(Exception e)` as it's bad practices to do this (this might even create an infinity loop in this case here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` or a `for` loop that will increment the loop count ONLY IF a valid input is provided. Your solution increments the loop counter automatically regardless of the validity of the input.

```
int i = 1;

while (i <= 5) {

    System.out.println("Enter number " + i + ": ");
        try{
            userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(userNumber <= 0){
                throw new Exception("The integer must be positive.");
            }
            sum = sum + userNumber; // this belongs after the negative check
            i++; // increment the count after all validations are successfully completed
        } catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("This data type is incorrect.");
            keyboard.nextLine();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose to use a `for` loop, remove the counter increment out of the loop declaration

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5;) {
    // your logic and exception handling here
    i++; // as in the while, increment only after all validations are successfully completed
}
```

Another point... I don't think it is necessary to throw an exception if the number is negative. I think it is better to simply execute a `continue` to avoid incrementing the loop counter. This is the result of this:

```
This program will give the sum and average of 5 positive integers,
Enter number 1: 
-5
The integer must be positive.
Enter number 1: 
-2
The integer must be positive.
Enter number 1: 
-3
The integer must be positive.
Enter number 1: 
-4
The integer must be positive.
Enter number 1: 
-5
The integer must be positive.
Enter number 1: 
1
Enter number 2: 
2
Enter number 3: 
3
Enter number 4: 
5
Enter number 5: 
4
The sum is 15 and the average of your 5 numbers is 3.
```

As you can see, I entered several negative numbers and the program continued to run without incrementing the loop counter.  The complete solution with `continue`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userNumber;
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("This program will give the sum and average of 5 positive integers,");
          
      for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ){
         System.out.println("Enter number " + i + ": ");
         try{
            userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(userNumber <= 0){
               System.err.println("The integer must be positive.");
               continue;
            }
            sum = sum + userNumber;
            i++;
         } catch(InputMismatchException e){
               System.out.println("This data type is incorrect.");
               keyboard.nextLine();
         } catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               keyboard.nextLine();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + " and the average of your 5 numbers is " + sum / 5 + ".");
}
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for! I totally forgot you could tell the loop how to increment the controlling variable from outside the parameter field. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BamronTasty don't forget to select this answer by clicking the check mark right next to it.

Comment: @BamronTasty for this specific use-case, the `while` loop is better because you have no choice but to control the increment of the loop counter. However, you can still use the loop SPECIFICALLY the way I showed here. Otherwise, even if you use `continue` when the next iteration starts, all parameters are reevaluated INCLUDING incrementing the loop counter. Since you only want to increment after successful validations, you (not the loop) need to control when it is incremented.

Comment: I know there are likely better ways to do this. My instructor was asking for very specific parameters for building the program. It needed a custom exception for negative numbers, needed to be a for loop, and we can't use concepts we haven't learned in the class. So that would strike continue from my list as well

Comment: @BamronTasty I didn't know that. That's OK. At least I was able to provide you with your required solution and one that's slightly better. And, you'll be able to use this approach in the future. Good luck with your remaining courses.

Answer (score 0):

```
class fivePositiveNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userNumber;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("This program will give the sum and average of 5 positive integers,");

        int ctr = 0;

        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Enter number " + (ctr+1) + ": ");
            try{
                userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                if(userNumber <= 0){
                    throw new Exception("The integer must be positive.");
                }
                sum = sum + userNumber;

                ctr++;
            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("This data type is incorrect.");
                keyboard.nextLine();
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            if (ctr == 5) break;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + " and the average of your 5 numbers is " + sum / 5 + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate this, while it does work, my instructor does not allow break statements on logic based loops, so I can't use them on for, while, or do while loops. Only cases and such. But thank you very much! I did learn from this, regardless

Comment: @BamronTasty your instructor is right. The break condition need not to be specified in the body of the loop regardless which loop implementation you choose.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't know your exact requirements, hence my solution.